# How to find number of distinct characters in a string

Tags: java, string, character, distinct

I have to count the number of distinct characters alphabet in the string, so in this case the count will be - 3 (`d`, `k` and `s`).

Given the following `String`:

```
String input;
input = "223d323dk2388s";
count(input);
```

My Code :

```
public int  count(String string) {
        int count=0;
        String character = string;
        ArrayList<Character> distinct= new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<character.length();i++){
            char temp = character.charAt(i);
            int j=0;
            for( j=0;j<distinct.size();j++){

                if(temp!=distinct.get(j)){

                    break;
                }

            }

            if(!(j==distinct.size())){
                distinct.add(temp);

            }
        }

        return distinct.size();
    }
```

Output : 3

Are there any native libraries which return me the number of characters present in that string ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Any sweet piece of try ? Didn't expect a question like this from you, who holds ~600 reputation on this site.

Comment: `public static String sweetPieceOfCode(String s){ return "3";}`

Comment: Seems like a homework. Please show us what you have tried so far. Try to follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how is the number of distinct characters in the above string 3?

Comment: how do you reach to 3 in above string. Please explain first yourself then us

Comment: i've read your profil...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With java 8 it is much easy. You could use something like this

```
return string.chars().distinct().count();
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to maintain an array and then fill it up and get the total. This checks for all characters including special characters and numbers.

```
boolean []chars = new boolean[256];

String s = "223d323dk2388s";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
  chars[s.charAt(i)] = true;
}

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
  if (chars[i]) count++;
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Here's an alternative if you want to calculate the count only of letters, not including numbers and special symbols. Note that capital and small alphabets are different.

```
boolean []chars = new boolean[56];
String s = "223d323dk2388szZ";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (ch >=65 && ch <= 90) {
        chars[ch - 'A'] = true;
    } else if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122) {
        chars[ch - 'a' + 26] = true; //If you don't want to differentiate capital and small differently, don't add 26
    }
}
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; ++i) {
    if (chars[i]) count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

---

Another way of doing it is using a Set.

```
String s = "223d323dk2388s";
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    set.add(s.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(set.size());
```

If you don't want numbers and special symbols.

```
String s = "223d323dk2388s";
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i){
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if ((ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) || (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122))
        set.add(s.charAt(i));
}
System.out.println(set.size());
```

Comment: Corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="InputString";
 String p="";
 char ch[]=s.toCharArray();
 for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
 {
     for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
     {
         if(ch[i]==ch[j])
         {
             ch[j]=' ';
         }
     }
     p=p+ch[i];
     p = p.replaceAll("\\s",""); 
 }
   
    System.out.println(p.length());
```

Comment: Edit and explain your answer please

Answer (score 1):

To those coming here looking for a solution in Kotlin:

```
val countOfDistinctCharacters = string.toCharArray().distinct().size
```